# Установка старого пакета MySQL server на Ubuntu 18.04. Могут ли быть проблемы?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

Были ли к кого проблемы, когда надо поставить пакет MySQL сервера не самой последней версии. Скажем так на 5 релизов назад от последнего. Будут ли проблемы в дальнейшем? Как лучше ставить на последние релизы в Debian/Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Если пакет собран под данную версию ОС — проблем быть не должно — разве что с безопасностью в результате того, что старые версии содержат незакрытые уязвимости и аналогично со старыми багами. Могут также быть проблемы с пакетами зависимыми от данного (несовместимость версий библиотек), но для MySQL скорей всего ничего страшного не случиться.

Если пакет собран под другую версию дистрибутива, то спектр проблем составляет от «неустановится» от нехватки зависимостей до «полностью нерабочей» из-за несовместимости библиотек. Смешение ветвей в бинарных дистрибутивах — дело трудное и подчас невозможное. Обычно в таких случаях можно пересобрать пакет более старой версии самостоятельно.

Answer (score 0):

Установка произвольных версий в любом линуксе часто похожа на рулетку. Иногда работает, иногда через раз. А риск разломать систему очень высок. И если это сервер, то и сломать бизнес.

Но теперь есть хорошее решение - называется [docker](https://docker.com/). С минимальными усилиями позволяет на одной машине держать несколько версий одного сервиса без риска все сломать. Просто нужно пойти на https://hub.docker.com/ и выбрать подходящий (часто уже базово настроенный) образ.

Для нужного Вам [MySql](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) прямо из коробки доступно [больше полусотни](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/mysql/tags/) версий. Также рядом лежат и особые образа - кластеры мускуля, под старые центоси собрано.